# Salto de linea en Servicio Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, replace

espero me puedan apoyar.
Investigue el tema del salto de linea y se que debo utilizar el replace para cambiar el `\n` por `<br />`, el asunto es que no se como realizarlo en un arreglo con varias variables donde tengo bastante texto.

```
@Injectable()
export class DetalleatService {
    private detalleat:Detalleat[] = [
        {
            imagen: "assets/img/LibroJob.png",
            nombrelibro: "Job",
            frase: "Un patriarca que experimentó el  poder de la fe",
            periodo: "Dentro del periodo pre-patriarcal posiblemente entre el año 2\.000a\.C\. y 1800 a\.C\.\.",
            autor: "Desconocido",
            tema: "El principio de toda sabiduría para los hebreos y para los cristianos está basado en el temor a Dios\. ",
            proposito: "Reconocer la soberanía de Dios, Job se arrepiente de su falta de FE y Dios le devuelve el doble de lo que tenía antes\.",
            bosquejo: "I\. El ataque de Satanás contra Job\. Job \(1\:1 al 2\:10\) \nII\. Job y sus amigos\. Job \(2\:11 al 31\:40\) III\. El mensaje de Eliú\. Job \(32 al 37\) IV\. Diagnóstico divino de Job\. Job \(38 al 42\:6\) V\. Bendición de Job\. Job \(42\:7-17\) ",
            datocurioso: "• Evidencia científica demuestra que fue el primer libro escrito de la Biblia\.",
            escritopara: "Quien quiera obtener el temor de Dios",
            versiculoclave:"Job 3\:25-26 25 Porque el temor que me espantaba me ha venido, Y me ha acontecido lo que yo temía\. 26 No he tenido paz, no me aseguré, ni estuve reposado; No obstante, me vino turbación\."
        },
    ];

getDetalleat():Detalleat[]{
    return this.detalleat;
    
}
}
export interface Detalleat {
    imagen: string;
    nombrelibro: string;
    frase: string;
    periodo: string;
    autor: string;
    tema: string;
    proposito: string;
    bosquejo: string;
    datocurioso: string;
    escritopara: string;
    versiculoclave: string;
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto quisiera por ejemplo que en el apartado del bosquejo me tomara el salto de linea:

[image: Bosquejo]

Comment: Hola. Por que lo quieres quitar?

Comment: Hola Angel, porque entiendo que cuando lo "reinderiza" al HTML no me pasa los saltos de linea y necesito que me tome los saltos de linea para que me quede mas organizado. Agradezco si me puedes colaborar. gracias.

Comment: No veo muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Puedes editar la pregunta y poner un ejemplo del resultado que quieres obtener?

Comment: Y si es posible, el resultado actual que obtienes actualmente.

Comment: Hola Angel, mira parte de como llamo el codigo desde html es de esta forma:<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron my-1 text-md-center bg-dark text-light" *ngFor="let locdetalleat of detalleat">
        <div class="row">                 <p class="card-text text-justify">{{ 'Bosquejo:' }}</p>
                <p class="card-text text-justify">{{ locdetalleat.bosquejo}}</p>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `[innerHTML]`y `datos.bosquejo.split("\n").join("<br />")` para lograr lo que quieres aplicado de esta manera:

Remplazamos `\n` por `<br />`:

```js
 prepararDatos(datos) {
    datos.bosquejo = datos.bosquejo.split("\n").join("<br />");

    return datos;
  }
```

Renderizamos las etiquetas reemplazadas:

```html
<p [innerHTML]="datos.bosquejo" >
</p>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brujio).

Comment: Hola Angel muchas gracias por tu aporte, me ayudo bastante, te puedo molestar con una ultima, como le agrego por ejemplo "Autor: Desconocido" a la misma linea: <p [innerHTML]="datos.autor" >
</p>

Comment: En ese caso no ocupas `[innerHTML]="datos.autor"` puedes hacerlo directamente como `Autor:{{datos.autor}}`